# Prompt password on disabling device admin privilage

Tags: android, device-admin

I have seen some applications like [applocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) in the playstore and I wonder how they prevent disable device admin privilege using a password prompt. I had some work around for the same but disappointed since the method **onDisableRequested** in my class which extends the **DeviceAdminReceiver** does not work for me instantly(*It can't start an activity instantly or it has some delay of 3-7 seconds to start an activity*).

I'am really sure there should be some other way to do it correctly.

**All I need is to show an activity that prompts for password immediately when the user presses on check box in device's device administrator window.**

Sorry for my bad English:-(

Comment: you can use `service`  or Countdown timer and check time .If it overcome 3 seconds then Your staff

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya: I dont understand

Comment: Please check the feature on applock